# Why is a macbook MSDOS formatted disk not showing up in windows?

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility

I followed this [apple documentation to format an external USB harddrive for windows](https://support.apple.com/en-za/guide/disk-utility/dskutl1010/mac).

I used Disk Utility and erased it to be `MS-DOS (FAT)` with Master Boot Record.

I then put it into my windows 10 pc and it did not show up - not even in Administrative Tools -> Computer Management -> Storage.

How do I make it recognised?

Comment: Is the disk less than 32 GB? Can you format it on the PC instead?

Comment: No, the disk is 500GB. Maybe but will have to do it during startup or with `gparted` (it is not being recognised on windows). Should choose ex-fat due to the disk being > 32GB?

Comment: Hmmm...looks like my front ports were not recognising the thing.

Comment: 500GB should be formatted exFat (as it says in the page you link to).